# Writing a script to find what computer a user is logged into

Tags: active-directory, powershell, scripting, user-accounts

So I want to specify a username and return the computer name. When I run this, it tells me that my `$computers` obj is `null`. Why would 
`$computers = Get-ADComputer | where {$_.accountdisabled -eq $false}` 
return `null`?

My script so far looks like this:

```
Function Get-Username{
$Global:Username = read-Host "Enter a username"
if ($Username -eq $null){
    Write-Host "Username can't be blank. Enter username"
    Get-Username
}
$UserCheck = Get-ADUser -Filter 'Name -like $Username' | FT Name, SamAccountName -A
if($UserCheck -eq $null){
    Write-Host "Invalid username, enter username"
    Get-Username
}
}

Get-username

$computers = Get-ADComputer | where {$_.accountdisabled -eq $false}
foreach($comp in $computers){
    $Computer = $comp.Name
    $ping = New-Object System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping
    $Reply = $null
    $Reply = $ping.send($Computer)
    if($Reply.status -like 'Success'){
        $proc = gwmi win32_process -computer $Computer -Filter "Name = 'explorer.exe'"
        ForEach($p in $proc){
            $temp = ($p.GetOwner()).User
            if($temp -eq $Username){
                Write-Host "$Username is logged on $Computer"
}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing I see is when i run 'Get-ADComputer' it wants a filter.

After the filter is applied i still dont see "accountdisabled" property for Get-AdComputer, I think you mean "Enabled"

```
$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * | where {$_.Enabled -eq $false}
```

You might want to change that filter before running.

Edit: sorry; to find the properties run `Get-ADComputer | Get-Member` this will show you a list of all properties.This is my #1 used cmdlet.